# Explain rsync's --blocking-io option

Tags: rsync, nonblocking

I have problems with understanding the --blocking-io option in rsync. Here's the descripton from the man page:

"This tells rsync to use blocking I/O when launching a remote shell transport.  If the remote shell is either rsh or remsh,  rsync  defaults to using blocking I/O, otherwise it defaults to using non-blocking I/O.  (Note that ssh prefers non-blocking I/O.)"

- When using rsync as the transport,
  i.e. you don't use -e, does this have
  an effect at all?
- I guess the result of running rsync
  with or without that option is the
  same and the difference is in 'how'
  rsync does the transfer?
- What's the main reason I would wanted
  to use this option? Performance?
  Looks like rsync provides sensible
  defaults for me, so why would I want
  to use it at all?
- And the last one: What does "Note
  that ssh prefers non-blocking I/O"
  mean?

Comment: Hello from the future, 2010 people. I have a note. One of your questions begins, "when using rsync as the transport, i.e. you don't use -e...". Not using "-e" doesn't necessarily imply that you're using rsync as the transport. Without the "-e" rsync falls back to plain ssh as a default remote shell transport. In order to not use a shell, and to use an rsync daemon as the transport, you have to explicitly specify the source or the destination using the host::module or rsync://host/module/ syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry part of my research got mixed up. That is my fault. (Corrected or added stuff is in italics)

Q1: Yes. Rsync uses asynchronous I/O (non-blocking). By using that option, you are forcing it to use blocking I/O mode. *This would be used when the remote shell (rsh) cannot handle non-blocking mode.*

Q2: Yes. The end result will be the same.

Q3: You would want to use this option *if the remote shell is not capable of handling non-blocking i/o*

Q4: *"Non-blocking mode makes sure when your connection dies, your screen session won't block ('hang')." ([http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xmCnC0y5QU0J:www.warp13.co.uk/irssissh+ssh+blocking+mode&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xmCnC0y5QU0J:www.warp13.co.uk/irssissh+ssh+blocking+mode&cd=13&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a)_)* SSH just prefers that

I hope that helps!

Comment: The article you mention uses the two terms in a different meaning, and the casual relation between "rsync is asynchronous by default" and "even if a single byte changes[...]" is inexistent.